# What is the difference between rm() and rm(list=ls())?

Tags: r

Most of articles, I have read. They recommend to use `rm(list=ls())` but I do not know what is the difference if I like to use `rm()`

Can I use `rm()` instead of `rm(list=ls())` if i would like to clear all variables?

Please give me some advices. Thanks.

Comment: `rm()` on its own doesn't do anything

Comment: try to see `?rm` and `?ls` . If you do `ls()`, it will list variables in your global environment.

Answer (score 18):

Command `rm(list=ls())` removes all objects from the current workspace (R memory), whereas `rm()` alone does not do anything. You have to specify to `rm()` what you want to remove. For example,

```
a<-1
rm(a)
```

would remove object `a` from you workspace. In contrast,

```
a<-1
b<-2
rm(a)
```

would remove just the object `a` from the memory, but leave the object `b` untouched. The following would remove both `a` and `b`:

```
a<-1
b<-2
rm(list=ls())
```

`rm(list=ls())` is easier to write than `rm(a, b)`, which also removes `a` and `b` from your environment, and scales to any number of objects. Imagine removing 100 objects by name: `rm(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h)` and so on...

You can give `rm()` a bunch of object to remove using the argument `list`. Because `ls()`lists all objects in the current workspace, and you specify it as the list of objects to remove, the aforementioned command removes all objects from the R memory.

Comment: For clear the R memory, I should use gc(), right? Do it need to use gc(list=ls())?

Comment: `gc()` is for garbage collection, which forces R to free the memory it might still have reserved, for the operating system. See `?gc()` in R for more information.

Comment: To be pedantic, rm(list= ls()) won't remove objects that start with a `.`. These can be removed with rm(list = ls(all.names = TRUE)) but I prefer to restart R

Comment: This answer is not correct as it stands. That command only would remove (non-'dotted') objects from the symbol list in the environment in which it is executed. It would NOT remove "all objects" from memory

Answer (score 4):

`rm()` is basically 'remove{base}', it is used to **Remove Objects from a Specified Environment**.

**Command `rm(list=ls())` means-**

`list=ls()` is base in this command that means you are referring to all the objects present in the workspace.

similarly, `rm()` is used to remove all the objects from the workspace when you use `list=ls()` as base.

However,
when it comes to using `rm()` **alone** it will not do anything as the 'base' is absent.

You can use `rm()` to remove specific variables to by putting them as 'base':

**For example**

```
a <-45                                                                          
rm(a)
```

Comment: I believe this is a potentially confusing answer for a new user. It uses the term "base" which also happens to be the name of the core namespace for the R program. `rm()` does nothing to objects in the `base`-namespace.