# R: What does `rm(list=ls())` do?

Tags: r

While looking at some R code written by someone else, I find near the top of the document `rm(list=ls())`.  I tried looking up what the `rm` function does and as far as I can tell it deletes specified variables from the workspace, so that if you had `x=3` somewhere, then after running `rm(x)` the variable `x` would behave as if it had never been assigned (so for instance would throw an error if you tried to print it).

But then the rest of the code is strange if I have this right, because it seems to be removing the empty list.  So it's not doing anything at all, right?  Is there a reason to have this code here?

Comment: The line removes all variables from the current environment.

Comment: This will help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43672774/what-is-the-difference-between-rm-and-rmlist-ls, also many consider this a not right practice, restart a R session is also a good choice

Comment: @PKumar's suggestion is spot on. Many people believe that you should `#`-comment that command when using it in questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the parameter list for the `rm` function is confusing, at least it was for me when I started using R. The `list` parameter is not actually supposed to be a list but rather a character vector. The `ls`-function does return a character vector of all the named objects visible in the environment where it is called and it has a default value that gets used if no other value is offered for its `envir` argument. If you do this at the console, then the default environment is the global environment. So this will clear all the "visible" objects (but not the ones defined in other namespaces or environments like the ones that exist in the `base`, `graphics`, `stats` or other loaded package-namespaces.

So now go look at `?ls` and `?rm` to better understand their capabilities. In particular new useRs should get their heads clear on the differences between R `names`, i.e. `symbols`, versus the character representations of them. The `ls` function is really reaching into the language level of R's implementation and returning a non-language-level value, whereas `rm` typically takes a language level input ... unless (as in this case) it is offered a value to its "list"-argument, ... which is not an R list. Clear? Maybe, hopefully, a bit more so.

Answer (score 5):

It clears all objects from the workspace.

Comment: It clears all objects ***that do not start with a period*** from the workspace.

Comment: `ls` only returns the names of objects in the environment in which it is called, and by default it only returns the non-dotted names, unless `all.names` is set to TRUE.

Comment: @42- yes, that's why I wrote 'workspace'. That's the current working environment.

Comment: I might be wrong about this but I think of the "current workspace" as comprising the entire search path.

Comment: @42- My understanding of the terminology is different, but I don't think it is particularly important. In any case I believe that with these comments the information has become clear.

Comment: I just looked up the word "workspace" in the R Language Definition. The first instance says: "The global environment is the root of the user workspace." So I'm taking that to mean my interpretation was consistent with that authority.